# How to get variables to search through an array, and check if numbers match

Tags: python

```
def comparing_numbers(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5, numbers(), correct_numbers):
    if number1 == numbers():
        correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1
print("")
if number2 == numbers():
    correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1
print("")
if number3 == numbers():
    correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1
print("")
if number4 == numbers():
    correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1
print("")
if number5 == numbers():
    correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1

comparing_numbers(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5, numbers(), correct_numbers)

print(correct_numbers)
```

So basically I need a bit of code which lets my five variables (number1, number2,number3,number4,number5,) search through an array called (numbers()) and if the number in the variables match any of the numbers in the array it adds one to my variable (correct_numbers). I need it to search five times (for each variable)

I've tried to make some code to explain what I'm saying, it defos doesnt work

Thanks

Comment: `(numbers())` is not array but function which you execute many times.

Comment: instead of `number1`, `number2`, etc. use list with numbers - `number[0]`, `number[1]` and use `for` to check alll elements.

Comment: you can't use `numbers()` in function definition `def name(..., numbers(), ...)`

Comment: Can you explain what you want with actual values and example output?

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do the work.

It checks for each number in your numbers if it appears in the list (array) given, and returns how many were found.

```
def findSimilars(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, all):

    correct_found = 0

    # all is a list of numbers to check if the numbers are in

    my_numbers = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5] # make the numbers a list for simple iteration

    for n in my_numbers: # go over each of the numbers
        if n in all: # if the current number is in my_numbers
            correct_found += 1

    return correct_found


all_numbers = [0,1,2] # ... All the values you want to check if your numbers are there
correct_times_found = findSimilars(1,2,3,4,5,all_numbers) # An example for function call
print "Number of times found: %d" % (correct_times_found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you store your numbers as a list?
If so:

```
numbersToCheck = [number1,number2,number3,number4,number5]
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

correct_numbers = len([num for num in numbers if num in numbersToCheck])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating code in your function, which probably belongs in a for loop.  See how we can simplify the function, and iterate over your list of numbers instead:

```
def comparing_numbers(check_numbers, numbers(), correct_numbers):
    for number in check_numbers:
        if number in numbers():
            correct_numbers += 1
    return correct_numbers

check_numbers = [number1, number2, number3, number4, number5]
correct_numbers = 0
print(comparing_numbers(check_numbers, numbers(), correct_numbers)
```

Comment: Why are you calling a function inside of a `def`? `numbers()`

Comment: Because the asker defined it that way: ".. search through an array called (numbers())..."

Comment: `def(..., numbers(), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are trying to do

```
def comparing_numbers(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5, numbers):
  correct_numbers = 0
  for number in [number1,number2,number3,number4,number5]:
    if number in numbers:
      correct_numbers += 1  
  return correct_numbers

correct_numbers = comparing_numbers(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5, numbers)

print(correct_numbers)
```

Answer (score -2):

The `in` statement checks if that number in in your set of numbers.
If it does, it adds one to correct_numbers.

```
if number1 in numbers:
    correct_numbers += 1
if number2 in numbers:
    correct_numbers += 1
if number3 in numbers:
    correct_numbers += 1
if number4 in numbers:
    correct_numbers += 1
if number5 in numbers:
    correct_numbers += 1
```